# trigger get/set on delete property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object which when changed, trigger a get/set:

```
class Main {
    private layers = {};
    get layerState () {
        return this.layers;
    }

    set layerState(layers: any) {
        this.layers = layers;
        console.log('change', layers)
    }
}

const m = new Main();

m.layerState = {toto: 1, tete : 2};
m.layerState = {...m.layerState, tutu: 2};
delete m.layerState.toto
```

the problem is, when I do `delete` the Set don't trigger.

what's a nice way to do in this case ?

Comment: The get *does* trigger

Comment: ok the get yes not the set

Comment: Are you going to `delete m.layerState` or `delete m.layerState.toto`?  If it's the latter I don't see why you'd expect anything to trigger... after all, if you write `m.layerState.tata = 3;` it wouldn't trigger `set LayerState()` because it's not reassigning `LayerState`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to understand - `set` happens when you performs an assignment, while `delete` removes a property from an object and does not assign a value to it.

So the `set` function will trigger if you try to **assign** a value like this - `obj.property = 'value'`;

Delete will not trigger it because it's not suppose to. If you want to trigger it before deletion, assign it to null and then delete it.

Also mentioned in the comments by @jcalz, when assigning a value to a property assign it to the property itself and not subproperties, and the setter does not recursively sets it.

```js
m.layerState = {toto: 1, tete : 2};
m.layerState = {...m.layerState, tutu: 2};
m.layerState = {...m.layerState, todo: null };
delete m.layerState.toto
```

There's also a hidden advantage in doing that, by assigning a value to null you are purging the reference, effectively reclaiming memory.

See more at - [delete operator MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

Comment: But `m.layerState.todo = null` doesn't trigger anything because you're not setting `m.layerState`.  A setter doesn't work recursively down through subproperties.

Comment: Yeah, the example code in the question is confusing to me because it seems to expect that deleting subproperties should be detectable.  You could use a `Proxy` to intercept a `delete` on any property of a class, but doing so for subproperties would require recursively wrapping thing with proxies, at which point 